# jQuery menu not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, menu, responsive

I'm building a menu that appears on click.
Basically, what I'm trying to do is to keep the "btn" appearing when the menu opens. Also, I can't figure out how to have an option to close the menu when i click out of the menu div. Thanks in advance

```js
var sidebarBox = document.querySelector('#box'),
    sidebarBtn = document.querySelector('#btn'),
    pageWrapper = document.querySelector('#page-wrapper');

sidebarBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  sidebarBtn.classList.toggle('active');
  sidebarBox.classList.toggle('active');
});

pageWrapper.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

  if (sidebarBox.classList.contains('active')) {
    sidebarBtn.classList.remove('active');
    sidebarBox.classList.remove('active');
  }
});

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

  if (sidebarBox.classList.contains('active') && event.keyCode === 27) {
    sidebarBtn.classList.remove('active');
    sidebarBox.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

```css
/*--------RESP MENU -------*/
#btn {
    float:right;
  top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: left 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
  transition: left 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
}
#btn div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms, background-color 250ms, -webkit-transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
  transition: opacity 500ms, background-color 250ms, -webkit-transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
  transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91), opacity 500ms, background-color 250ms;
  transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91), opacity 500ms, background-color 250ms, -webkit-transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
}

#btn.active {
  left: 230px;
        z-index:999 !important;


}
#btn.active div {
  background-color: #343838;
        z-index:999 !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
#btn.active #top {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px) rotate(-135deg);
          transform: translateY(10px) rotate(-135deg);
}
#btn.active #middle {
  opacity: 0;
  /* transform: rotate(135deg); */
}
#btn.active #bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
}

#box {
  position: fixed;

  overflow: auto;
  top: 0px;
  right: -275px;
  width: 275px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  color: #343838;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
  transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
}

#box.active {
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
    z-index:4;
}

#items {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#items .item {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
  transition: all 250ms;
}
#items .item:hover {
  padding: 15px 45px;
  background-color: rgba(52, 56, 56, 0.2);
}

#btn, #btn * {
  will-change: transform;
}

#box {
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}
```

```html
                    <div id="btn">
                      <div id='top'></div>
                      <div id='middle'></div>
                      <div id='bottom'></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="box">
                      <div id="items">
                        <div class="item">Item 1</div>
                        <div class="item">Item 2</div>
                        <div class="item">Item 3</div>
                        <div class="item">Item 4</div>
                        <div class="item">Item 5</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
1.You need to assign z-index values to negative value when #box.active
2.You can use event.target.nodeName to find outside of the DIV menu
```

```js
var sidebarBox = document.querySelector('#box'),
    sidebarBtn = document.querySelector('#btn');

sidebarBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  sidebarBtn.classList.toggle('active');
  sidebarBox.classList.toggle('active');
});

$(document).on("click",function(e) {
  if(event.target.nodeName != "DIV"){
    sidebarBtn.classList.remove('active');
    sidebarBox.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

```css
/*--------RESP MENU -------*/
#btn {
  float:right;
  top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: left 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
  transition: left 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
}
#btn div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms, background-color 250ms, -webkit-transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
  transition: opacity 500ms, background-color 250ms, -webkit-transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
  transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91), opacity 500ms, background-color 250ms;
  transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91), opacity 500ms, background-color 250ms, -webkit-transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
}

#btn.active {
  left: 230px;
  z-index:999 !important;
}
#btn.active div {
  background-color: #343838;
  z-index:999 !important;
  opacity: 1;
}
#btn.active #top {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px) rotate(-135deg);
  transform: translateY(10px) rotate(-135deg);
}
#btn.active #middle {
  opacity: 0;
  /* transform: rotate(135deg); */
}
#btn.active #bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
}

#box {
  position: fixed;

  overflow: auto;
  top: 0px;
  right: -275px;
  width: 275px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  color: #343838;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
  transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
}

#box.active {
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index:-10;
}

#items {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#items .item {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
  transition: all 250ms;
}
#items .item:hover {
  padding: 15px 45px;
  background-color: rgba(52, 56, 56, 0.2);
}

#btn, #btn * {
  will-change: transform;
}

#box {
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn">
  <div id='top'></div>
  <div id='middle'></div>
  <div id='bottom'></div>
</div>
<div id="box">
  <div id="items">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s79mu3c5/)